# Easy jQuery issue

Tags: jquery

If I have a table where a td has a class called "clicky" with the following jQuery code:

```
$(".clicky").click(function()
{
 var td = $(this);
 $.post("http://URL/file.php", {val:value})
 .done(function(data)
  {
   $(td).empty().append("hello");
  });
});
```

How can I replace the HTML in the td that was clicked with the HTML code returned in the data variable? I do not individually name my TDs, so I cannot reference it directly.

Simply using $(this).innerHTML() seems to be out of scope or dysfunctional...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use html() to replace the existing innerHTML

```
td.html(data);
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried and I was going crazy wondering what the heck I was missing. Must have been a typo; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
$(td).empty().append("hello");
```

With

```
td.html(data);
```

this will replace HTML from your `td` tag with data from post request